Bitlocker and dump file creation in Windows
My machine is a Thinkpad, running Windows 11, with Bitlocker enabled on the (1 TB) SSD.
To investigate unexplained power-offs that have plagued me for a long time, I'm trying to obtain the DMP files that should be generated by Windows during crashes -- specifically, C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Unfortunately, this is never generated after said power-offs -- a post-reboot entry in Event Viewer just laughably says Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation.
I've spent a lot of time looking into why this happens and at what phase the failure is happening. Does it happen at crash-time when generating the dump into the pagefile? Or does it happen afterwards post-reboot when the dump is copied from the pagefile into MEMORY.DMP?
A few comments/threads like this have suggested that an encrypted disk (e.g. with Bitlocker) may be responsible, but they don't say exactly how. I've found nothing in Windows docs that suggests Bitlocker presents any limitations for crash dumps, or anything anywhere on how to work around such limitations.
Does anyone know if/how Bitlocker impacts dump file creation? What may be done to work around any limitations? (Disabling Bitlocker is not an option, by policy -- even for separate partitions, I need to enable Bitlocker eventually.)
(My pagefile is System-Managed and I've more than enough free disk space for Windows to dump all of my 32 GB of RAM, if necessary. Assume that it's a fresh machine with un-corrupted disk.)

Does that Event Log message show up after every power-off? Does the BSOD show up before a power-off?

@JoepvanSteen yeah I tried the manual creation but with the Power Button option, but for some reason, that didn't trigger a crash after the expected 7s -- all I got was my PC powered off if I continue holding the button for up to 10s.

So I later tried the NotMyFault app, which allows one to trigger different types of crash. This did work but my results were mixed -- the MEMORY.DMP file was generated (about 2.4 GB), but I still see the Event Viewer error, post-reboot. It's worth mentioning that this test was carried out only after I'd created a separate partition with no Bitlocker and pointed Windows at it, just to test. So I don't know if the MEMORY.DMP was generated because of the nature of the non-Bitlocker partition or because NotMyFault crashes in a different way from my power-offs.

@grawity_u1686 I don't know if I get BSODs because the power-offs usually happen while the laptop is supposed to be asleep, lid-closed. I also can't reproduce them reliably -- it can take a week or two between power-offs. For now, I'm more interested in first getting the crash dumps working, then hopefully, they reveal more of what's going on.

No, it doesn't show up after every power-off. Filtering Event Viewer logs for those VolMgr entries, shows it mostly (maybe only) happens after a crash or or one of those odd power-offs.

I can confirm that bitlocker does NOT prevent MEMORY.DMP creation - I have a couple PCs that have done it in the last month. If the pc blue-screens, it should always generate a system event with ID 1001 on startup, saying "The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck" with some more info - is that the one you're looking at? There are some crash types that can interrupt creating a dump, like if your ssd driver broke

@Cpt.Whale thanks for confirming -- to be clear, your dumps were MEMORY.DMP, not Minidumps, correct? I've done some filtering now and I see your "bugcheck" entry only for the BSODs which I deliberately triggered using NotMyFault on the same day. For the problematic power-off events, Windows couldn't be more vague, all I get is a combo of The previous system shutdown at xx:xx:xx on ‎xx/‎xx/‎2024 was unexpected. followed by shortly after by Dump file creation failed due to error during dump creation..

(For anyone wondering, I didn't use the Keyboard method to force a crash, because I don't have the necessary Scroll Lock key on my builtin keyboard, and didn't want to bother with creating a new button combo, since the Power Button was already an okay alternative.)

@beqti yes, not minidumps - the related message is at the end of the 1001 event: A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Your PC didn't BSOD if it doesn't generate event 1001. There are few exceptions, like if your ssd detached, the laptop overheated or power supply failure, then windows can't write anything before stopping

Buttocks does NOT impact the generation of memory dumps, so your system being unable to do so, has absolutely  nothing to do with BitLocker. Since this is a corporate machine have you asked your IT staff to investigate the problem?

BitLocker….whatever word I used was caused by autocorrect

Since the question mentions a Thinkpad, do the unexplained power-offs happen when the Thinkpad running from the battery and/or AC mains power?

@Ramhound Yep, already tried that, didn't get far. Chester, they happen typically when it's running from battery e.g. I find out on some morning that it powered off sometime during the night. Anyways, thanks all for confirming, I guess I'll wait till the power-off happens again and hope that the dump file is generated this time into the new partition, bitlocked or no. Else, I'll keep looking for other things that could be blocking the dump file creation.

I suspect you're looking in the wrong direction, because:

Unfortunately, this is never generated after said power-offs

As far as I know, Windows crashes don't normally result in power-offs – they result in reboots – therefore power-offs cannot be OS crashes, and therefore power-offs won't cause a memory dump to be generated.

I'd agree with this if it weren't for the logs that mention the failed dump creation. Do you have any proof that Windows generates these logs everytime the device is powered off unexpectedly, not only for crashes? (I'm not sure if I can reproduce/simulate such a power-off easily with a laptop, having a battery and all.)

@beqti - By the very nature of the situation, nothing can be generated if the machine unexpectedly turns off.

@Ramhound Yes, that much is obvious -- what I'm asking is, if this is some blitz power-off, why is Windows checking for a dump at all post-reboot, and complaining when it cannot find one? There was no bugcheck as far as Windows logs show, so why check for a dump file? If the presumption here is that Windows always performs this check for every odd power-off, is there any proof of this e.g. by simulating such a power-off with a desktop machine and checking if Windows logs show a similar "dump file creation failed" post-reboot?

Windows can be aware it suddenly crashed because of the absence of something it expects.

@Ramhound ("crash" meaning "power off" in your comment, not a software crash) Yes, Windows can, but is there any evidence that's what likely happened here? For instance, I realized I'd been too focused on the System Logs. Looking at the App Logs around the same time, I see "APPCRASH" and "LiveKernelEvent" events caused by corporate malware Websense (wepsvc.exe). I remember reading that these things hook deep past the usual OS protections, so I'd not be surprised if they crashed without raising a BSOD and/or skipping all the usual dump actions + reboot. This has now become my main suspect.

Apologize, when I saw Windows can be aware that it crashed, I do mean the system suddenly shutdown (loss of power) instead of a controlled memory dump and restart.

That's alright. Thinking again (after the "power off" happened again), I now belatedly realize that since I have Bitlocker enabled, it could well be that the device is in fact rebooting each time -- because I'm not there to enter the Bitlocker pin with the lid closed, Bitlocker will naturally power off the laptop again, that's its normal behaviour if you don't enter the pin quickly enough. Therefore, all reboot/crashes while the lid is closed, will eventually become power-offs.

I just received confirmation during a troubleshooting session with Microsoft that BitLocker was causing the creation to fail. After disabling BitLocker, the file was successfully written. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be any official documentation confirming this.

Oh wow, what are the odds? Was your issue the same as or similar to mine? Is your troubleshooting session available to the public through the usual online forums?

Also, how technical was this session, did they inspect any data from your event logs, etc. -- I ask because I've often seen support people on forums just chalk up problems to the nearest plausible thing, with little/no actual evidence, just to end the discussion. And did they offer any workaround besides disabling Bitlocker?
